# Joined regexes in python sometimes fail

Tags: python, regex

I'm using regexes to validate that some data is in the correct format and having it sometimes fail.

I have data entries multiple fields. Only a few fields are consistent enough in format or never blank to be validated, so I created a small regex to match those. I want to join the fields and the regexes together and call match() once per entry. Although all the individual fields match their respective regexes, the joined check fails.

```
regs = ['\d.\d','[a-z][a-z]','\d{1,2}'] # list of regexes
indeces = [4, 15, 77] # list of indeces
for line in stdin:

    linesplit = line.rstrip().split('\t')
    testline = []
    for index in indeces:
        testline.append(linesplit[index])

    for i, e in enumerate(testline):
        print i, e, re.match(regs[i], e)
```

This works fine, but when I try the last bit, it sometimes fails.

```
fullregex = re.compile('\t'.join(regs))
f = fullregex.match('\t'.join(testline).rstrip())
print 'F', f, '!'
```

Is there an issue with my fullregex or are the matches I'm getting just false positives?

Comment: Each regex is only going to validate a portion of the field. Is there a reason to revalidate in a joined regex and testline?

Comment: The portions were there for testing to see if a field was not matching. What I'm after is the final one matching as that was faster when I ran it.

Comment: Then you should skip joining the regexs' and make it static complete. This results in even faster performance. `'\d.\d[^\t]*\t[^\t]*[a-z][a-z][^\t]*\t[^\t]*\d{1,2}'`

Comment: Exact match functional equivalent's `['^\d.\d$','^[a-z][a-z]$','^\d{1,2}$']` ~ `'^\d.\d\t[a-z][a-z]\t\d{1,2}$'`

Answer (score 1):

Your individual regular expressions can match *within* a column, but your joined expression won't.

For example, the input:

```
['1.1 bar', 'hello', '123 is a number']
```

matches your individual expressions, but when joined with tabs in between no longer matches the `fullregex` pattern.

Add `[^\t]*` as 'padding' into your expressions to allow for extra not-tab characters around the tabs:

```
fullregex = re.compile(r'[^\t]*\t[^\t]*'.join(regs))
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> regs = ['\d.\d','[a-z][a-z]','\d{1,2}']
>>> testline = ['1.1 bar', 'hello', '123 is a number']
>>> for i, (expr, line) in enumerate(zip(regs, testline)):
...     print i, line, re.match(expr, line)
... 
0 1.1 bar <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101c17e68>
1 hello <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101c17e68>
2 123 is a number <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101c17e68>
>>> re.match('\t'.join(regs), '\t'.join(testline))
>>> re.match(r'[^\t]*\t[^\t]*'.join(regs), '\t'.join(testline))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101c17e68>
```

If you wanted your regular expressions to validate the *whole* column, then either:

1. test each column with `zip()` and anchors (`^` and `$`):

   ```
   all(re.match('^{}$'.format(expr), col) for expr, col in zip(regs, testline))
   ```

   where `all()` only returns `True` if all expressions matched and the anchors make sure the expression covers the whole column, not just a subset.
2. or join the columns with `\t`, but do add anchors as well:

   ```
   re.match('^{}$'.format('\t'.join(regs)), '\t'.join(testline))
   ```

Demo:

```
>>> regs = ['\d.\d','[a-z][a-z]','\d{1,2}']
>>> testline = ['1.1', 'he', '12']
>>> all(re.match('^{}$'.format(expr), col) for expr, col in zip(regs, testline))
True
>>> re.match('^{}$'.format('\t'.join(regs)), '\t'.join(testline))
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x101caa780>
>>> testline = ['1.1 bar', 'hello', '123 is a number']
>>> all(re.match('^{}$'.format(expr), col) for expr, col in zip(regs, testline))
False
>>> re.match('^{}$'.format('\t'.join(regs)), '\t'.join(testline)) is None
True
```

Comment: That would allow the entries you wrote in testline to match? That's not what I'm after. I'm looking to match exactly. For example, the middle one should match only two lower case letters.

Comment: @Wineblood: Right, but your *original* three tests allowed for those matches. You never limited those to only match the *whole* column.